# how to get home page url in orchard cms

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am building module to register customers and after registration i need to redirect the   user to home page (default). I cant see a way as in Orchard everything works as content items.

Some of my code from Controller is given below

```
             $ if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return new ShapeResult(this, _services.New.Checkout_Signup(Signup:  signup));

        var customer = _customerService.CreateCustomer(signup.Email, signup.Password);
        customer.FirstName = signup.FirstName;
        customer.LastName = signup.LastName;
        customer.Title = signup.Title;

        _authenticationService.SignIn(customer.User, true);

        return Redirect("~/Home Page URL here...");
```

Comment: So the home page is not "/", no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Orchard, the home page has an empty string for its alias.  It's possible to look up the `RouteValueDictionary` of an alias by calling the `IAliasService.Get()` method.  Once you have this, you can simply pass it to `RedirectToRoute()`.

So for the home page:

```
var homepage = _aliasService.Get(String.Empty);
return RedirectToRoute(homepage);
```

You can see Orchard using this mechanism to check the home page in the `AutoroutePartDriver.cs` file lines 66 - 72 in version 1.7.2.